# Get list of all declared module imports (SystemJS)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm

I'm using jspm and SystemJS to import ES2015 modules.

Is it possible to get a list of all of the imported modules in a project through the `System` object, or anywhere else? I can access my project-specific modules through `System._loader.moduleRecords`, but the modules that I've installed through jspm (e.g., `d3`, `jquery`) do not appear in this list.

`System._loader.modules` contains a list of *all* modules, but unfortunately also includes a list of modules required to transpile my code and modules-loading packages.

**`System._loader.moduleRecords`** (project modules)
[image]

**`System._loader.modules`** (project modules, libraries, transpile packages)
[image]

**I want only a list of *declared* imports, specifically, those that I've imported using `import x from 'x'`.** This should include *both* project modules and libraries, but *not* babel/module-loading related modules. I'd like the solution to not involve filtering using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SystemJS Debugger](https://github.com/peteruithoven/systemjs-debugger) is probably what you are looking for.